# .NET Core - AddHttpClient retornando null

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Em um projeto ASP.NET WebApi estou tentando registrar no container de DI um cliente http tipado.
Mas ao tentar configurar utilizando o service provider acaba retornando null no serviço.

```
Ambiente de runtime:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19043
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.6
  Commit:  478b2f8c0e

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.407 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Segue exemplo de como tentei configurar

```
public interface IClient {}
public class Client : IClient {}

//No startup
services.Configure<Config>(config => new Config());
services.AddHttpClient<IClient, Client>((provider, http) =>
{
  var config = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<Config>>().Value;
  http.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.Url.Value);
});
```

Mas ao inspecionar o ServiceCollection mostra o seguinte
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Dentro da startup você pode utilizar o IConfiguration no lugar do IOptions.

```
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddHttpClient<IClient, Client>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration.GetSection("YourConfig").Value);
        });
        // ...
    });
```